# I want to create only a new association, using Sequelize (really simple question)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to create a new association only, and I’m confused with the use of Sequelize in this matter

I have Countries and Activities, with a relation many to many, Creating the relationship is just doing

```
Country.belongsToMany(Activity, { through: 'Country_Activity' });
Activity.belongsToMany(Country, { through: 'Country_Activity' });
```

This ‘Country-Activity’ table will be created by sequelize

When I want to create a new instance, of say, a Country, I code:

```
Country.create({
   name: "name",
   Activity: {...}
},{
   include: Activity
})
```

What if I want to add a new association (a new Activity) for a Country, the Country already exists, but I just want to add a new association to it

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only solution I've found is:

```js
const country = await Country.create({
   name: "name",
})
const myActivityIds = [1]//or whatever the desired Id is 
await country.setActivities(myActivityIds)
```

Here is the documentation on create with associations. I hope I'm mistaken and you can find a better way! https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html#hasmany---belongstomany-association

Comment: it is creating the country, which is something that I don´t want. I guess that I'll have to get the country, delete it, and recreate it, there should be a better way.